# Как в jQuery по клику получать содержимое тегов?

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица, строки которой выводятся через php @foreach. Как по нажатию кнопки получать (выводить на экран) содержимое всех тегов в данной таблице?

```html
<table id="table1"> 
            <tr>
                <td>{{++$num3}} </td>
                <td>{{$item3->PIN}}</td>
                <td>{{$item3->BRAND}}</td>
                <td>{{$item3->NAME}}</td>
                <td>{{$item3->RVALUE}}</td>
                <td>{{$item3->PRICE}}</td>
                <td>
                 <input id="cart"  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm br0"
                 value="В корзину"></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо получить текст соседних ячеек в выбранной строке таблицы, то например так

```js
$("input").click(function(){
   var txt = $(this).closest("td")
                    .siblings()
                    .get()
                    .map(td => $(td).text());
   console.log(txt); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1"> 
    <tr>
       <td>раз </td>
       <td>два</td>
       <td>три</td>
       <td>
          <input id="cart"  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm br0"                      value="В корзину">
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Если же речь все-так идет прямо обо всех значениях из таблицы то надо посмотреть в сторону чего-то подобного:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("td:not(:last-child)")....
```